# Switch with an if statement C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to Write a program that simulates a initial phone call to a bank where the user enters the options:
•Press 1 for English, 2 for Spanish
–If English (1)
» Press 1 for balance, 2 for payment, 3 for transfer, 4 to talk to someone
•(Switch case)
•1: “balance” •2: “payment” •…..
–Else, if Spanish (2)
•(Switch case)
•1: “el balance” •2: “el payment” •….. El …

This is what I have so far, I cannot get the switch to run?

```
int choice = 0;
int language;
const int English = 1;
//const int Spanish = 2;

Console.WriteLine("Please select 1 for English");
Console.WriteLine("Seleccione 2 para español");
language = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// Console.WriteLine("Pulse 1 para el saldo bancario , 2 para el pago, 3 para la transferencia , 4 para hablar con alguien");
Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for balance, 2 for payment, 3 for transfer, 4 to talk to someone");

switch (choice)
{
    case 1: Console.WriteLine("Balance");
    break;
    case 2: Console.WriteLine("Payment");
    break;
    case 3: Console.WriteLine("Transfer");
    break;
    case 4: Console.WriteLine("Please hold");
    break;
}
```

Anyone willing to direct me in the right direction?

Comment: Choice is always 0, yafter WriteLine you need to ReadLine to see what the user has entered.

Comment: r u getting an error? can u please post the error msg?

Comment: No error, the switch just "kick in".

Comment: Duh, I must've inadvertantly deleted the ReadLine during the editing. Thanks, always nice to have a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

The choice variable is always 0. You need to get that for the switch statement to work. Try this before your switch statement:

```
choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not taking any input from the user.

You need something like

```
int choice = (int) Console.ReadLine();
```

before your switch statement.

See [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-readline) for more information on how to use  the Console.ReadLine() function.

Answer (score 0):

add before switch statement

```
choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

and also use this into your `switch satement` to have an output in case they input other value:

```
default: Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                             break;
```